# Users unable to edit all list items despite list setting SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, access-denied

I'm working with an organization that is using SharePoint Online, and we've set up a list for collaboration. Their SharePoint admins don't have a lot of experience with SP (and I only have a little), and I'm trying to help them troubleshoot an issue that we're experiencing with editing Items in the List. Note: I have to do this remotely and without Full Control permissions myself. I'm hoping that someone here could tell me what the potential Permissions or settings are that they should be looking at to identify/fix the problem.

Issue: Users can Create, Edit, and Delete their own Items in the List, but cannot Edit or Delete Items created by other users. Each time a user tries to Edit someone else's Item, they get the "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

Desired Function: All users should be able to Edit any Item on the List.

Steps Taken So Far:

- I've confirmed that the Item-Level Permissions under List>Advanced Settings has Read access: Read all items, and Create and Edit access: Create and edit all items toggled.
- I have asked about current Permission levels for the users, but they haven't told me so far what the users have.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the list level settings are correct, it is possible that the individual items have stopped inheriting permissions.  select the dropdown menu for an item and click manage permissions, check that the item is inheriting permission from its parent (the list)

Comment: Thanks NiceNix. It looks like it was a permissions issue. I had them break permissions inheritance at the list level and give users Design permission level instead of Edit and that fixed the problem. I thought Edit was supposed to allow users to edit each other's entries, but it looks like that wasn't the case.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround.  For the record, Design level permissions SHOULD only be required to edit other people's items when the list is set to use Item Level Permissions (which you indicate in the question is not the case)  Personally, I would still be concerned that the list is not behaving correctly and would recreate it (if that can be done without losing data)